Is there a simple way to describe a list of equal objects in XAML?
I have a list of 34 column definitions, the list looks as follows:
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Is there an easier way to do this? The amount is fixed.

UniformGrid <UniformGrid Columns="34" ...>

Easier way to do what, exactly?

Identical columns and one row. Sounds like a horizontal StackPanel. (No "column definitions")

You can either use an UniformGrid (like said in the comment).
The content will be added column after column.
<UniformGrid Columns="34">
    <Label/> <!--c1-->
    <Label/> <!--c2-->
    <Label/> <!--c3-->
    <!-- ... -->
</UniformGrid>

Or create a class, inherit from Grid and add a property for the number of columns. You will keep the behaviour of a Grid.
class GridWithFixedNbrCol : Grid
{
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return ColumnDefinitions.Count; }
        set
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
    }
}

The content is added in the right column with Grid.Column like a normal grid
<local:GridWithFixedNbrCol Columns="34">
    <Label Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="17"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="18"/>
</local:GridWithFixedNbrCol>


Subclassing in wpf is rarely required. Rather make an attached behavior (either a normal attached property or with Interaction.Behaviors), which sets column definition. As a bonus it will be supporting bindings. Tip: use string property rather than int to define each column individually, that would make behavior more re-usable. Layouts with Grid are often a mix of columns/rows with star units and auto, sometimes you need GroupName or pixels.

I am sadly not familiar enough with 'Interaction.Behaviors' but I would be interested to see how it would be done for this case.  The int property is used here to define the number of columns, not the width since the OP did not seem to care having different width values for the columns. That's why uniformgrid seems to be the cleanest/easiest option for it's case

How about using attached properties and syntax like this:
<!-- Define xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Behaviors" -->
<!-- Create 5 columns: 1/3 width, 2/3 width, auto, auto and 50 pixels -->
<Grid b:GridBehavior.Columns="1*,2*,,auto,50"> ... </Grid>

Implementation:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Behaviors;

public class GridBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Columns", typeof(string), typeof(GridBehavior), new PropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
        {
            if (s is not Grid grid)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must be Grid.");

            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(GridLength));

            var columns = e.NewValue.ToString()!.Split(",").Select(o =>
            {
                if (o == "")
                    return new ColumnDefinition();
                else if (converter.ConvertFromString(o) is GridLength gridLength)
                    return new ColumnDefinition { Width = gridLength };
                return new ColumnDefinition();
            });

            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            foreach (var column in columns)
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
        }));

    public static string GetColumns(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
    public static void SetColumns(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);

}

You can omit verbose xaml to define columns in many cases.
In your specific case the value will be
b:GridBehavior.Columns=",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"

which isn't bad, right?
TODO: multiplier for repeated columns, support GroupName (as suffix #SomeGroupName?), do same for rows.
